# Configuring Eclipse Runtime

Tags: eclipse, configuration, runtime

I am creating an Eclipse runtime application, however I am having an issue with external archives.

Is it possible to configure Eclipse to include a specific library when any project is created? For instance, if I create a Java project I get JUnit and myjar.jar automatically included in the project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Window -> 
  Preferences ->
  Java ->
  Installed JREs and add your desired jar.

**Screenshots:**

---

[image: Installed JRES screenshot]

---

[image: Jre definition]

Comment: I tried this, however it is giving me an access restriction on the library I've added. Any indications please? Thanks :)

Comment: Remove the JRE Library and add it again